# How to join two tables with redundant column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named ServiceIOD and ServiceSubs and between them only one column named ShortCode is common. So, when I try to join these two tables to get the combined result for some given short code it is not giving me the correct output. May be it is because the ShortCode column is holding redundant data for both table. For example we can find shortcode=36788 multiple times in both tables for multiple rows. The query I tried so far is as below:

```
 SELECT distinct serviceIOD.keyword, 
        serviceIOD.shortcode 
   FROM serviceIOD 
        INNER JOIN serviceSubs 
            ON serviceIOD.shortcode = serviceSubs.shortcode 
            AND serviceIOD.shortcode = 36788
```

I would appreciate any sort of help from you all. Thank you.

UPDATE:

Explanation of incorrect output : I am getting total of 24 rows when I am joining by this query for `shortcode` 36788 but when I query separately in two tables for the `shortocde` 36788 I get 24 rows for `ServicesIOD` table and 3 rows for `ServicesSubs` table. All together 27 rows. But when I join with the query above I get only 24 rows.

Comment: Can you post some sample data..

Comment: "So, when I try to join these two tables to get the combined result for some given short code it is not giving me the correct output." What output do you get? What's incorrect about it? What would the correct output actually be? What do your tables look like? Can you post a sample of the data in both of them?

Comment: Ok the incorrect output is like I am getting total of 24 rows when I am joining by this query for shortcode 36788 but when I query separately in two tables for the shortocde 36788 I get 24 rows for ServicesIOD table and 3 rows for ServicesSubs table. All together 27 rows. But when I join with the query above I get only 24 rows.

Comment: @barsan [Discover SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: the explanation makes zero sense. you cannot add the two numbers, that's `UNION`.

Comment: do you know what `distinct` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with this following query:

```
 SELECT serviceIOD.keyword, 
 serviceIOD.shortcode 
 FROM serviceIOD where shortcode = 36788
 UNION select serviceSubs.keyword, 
 serviceSubs.shortcode  from serviceSubs where shortcode = 36788
```

Thank you everyone for taking your valuable time to help me on my problem. And special thanks to @Optimuskck as I got my answer idea from his suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.Usually the UNION is avoiding duplication entries.

```
(SELECT serviceIOD.keyword, 
serviceIOD.shortcode 
FROM serviceIOD) 
UNION (select * from serviceSubs)
WHERE serviceIOD.shortcode = 36788
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is giving error in where condition. SO that I have changed the query like this : SELECT serviceIOD.keyword, 
serviceIOD.shortcode 
FROM serviceIOD where shortcode = 36788
UNION select serviceSubs.keyword, 
serviceSubs.shortcode  from serviceSubs where shortcode = 36788 and now it is working. Thanks a lot or your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `Inner Join` and the `shortcode` 36788, filters rows that match between the two tables, and knowing that you've already made a test on the `serviceSubs` table and got `3` rows, the result of the join will be `3` rows too, but then you perform a `select distinct` on both `keyword` and `shortcode`, so this query looks for a distinct `keyword` where the `shortcode` value is 36788, that's why you get `24` rows.

Let me know if i'm wrong so I can delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got 3 rows in seviceSubs table with different Keyword and same shortcode. So I think it is not because of the Distinct keyword.

Comment: Yes, I didn't express it well, I think you get 24 rows, with the same shortcode and a different keyword in each row,which makes each of them distinct, but It doesn't matter, now that you've got your answer ;)